# Groupin by on multiple columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a panda dataframe which has the following columns, `year`, `month`, `source` and some other field. I would like to group by `year`, `month` and `source` I want the `source`` to appear as a column, after groupby.

```
           source1, source2, source3,....
2017, jan
2017, feb
...
```

This is how my code looks like

```
df.pivot_table(index = ['year','month'], columns = 'source', aggfunc = np.size, fill_value = 0)
```

but I'm getting the following error message

```
Reindexing only valid wit uniquely valued index objects
```

Comment: show us some data ?

Comment: Can you provide a dataframe with example data? I understand the problem but, honestly, am too lazy to mock up a dataframe from scratch.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe

Comment: you can always use `df.melt()` and `df.pivot_table()`

Comment: I revised my original question, could you have a look

Comment: @H.Z. here is a similar question I answered. It may guide you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539325/how-to-pivot-table-so-the-columns-can-also-be-part-of-the-index/49559384#49559384

Comment: what should I put as the 'values' in the pivot_table?

Comment: @H.Z. without seeing the data I am guessing you dont need it. you can remove `value_name` from `df.melt` and remove `values` from `df.pivot_table`

Comment: do I have to use melt as well? Can't I just use pivot_tale?

Comment: should I first do a group by and then use the pivot_table?